# Use a Flash Device for ReadyBoost with SSD

Tags: windows-7, memory, ssd, readyboost

I have a rather old computer - an Asus Zenbook with just 4GB of RAM, and a 128GB SSD.

Using Firefox, running a few tabs simultaneously, I sometimes get a notification telling me the system is running out of memory, and that I have to close a few programs to make sure I don't lose information (I don't have then any choice other than restarting the browser or restarting my PC).

For this, I thought about expanding my laptop's memory capacity with the RB feature, though I get a message saying that because I have an SSD drive, my computer wouldn't benefit from the RB drive.

I guess the problem is my SSD having just a few gigabyte of space left, which probably gets full quickly on strenuous periods.

I couldn't find answers related to my case, which is probably less common.

I hope I could explain everything well enough, this isn't my mother tongue.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Redi Boost is to increase performance (and so is less useful on SSD drives).  It does not increase basic disk capacity.

If it is not practical to get a larger SSD drive, then consider getting a USB Drive and move older Documents from your Document storage to the USB Drive. This will free up space on your main drive.

Overall, you are hampered by a very small disk. It would be worthwhile to get a larger one if you can.